# mvc is not working on my host

Tags: php

I`m using PDO databaseconnect 
PHP programming with classes and objects in a MVC-model.

i made a website that works 100% on my own localhost
but when i uploaded it to my host (and ofcourse changed the database connection data),
it didn`t work. the html i include in my view.php(MVC) is not been added to the page. though i tested if the view.php file is included and it is. so is there any prep needed to make my render function work?

view.php

```
class View{
    public function render($url = "", $data = true){
        include "app/views/template/header.php" ;
        include "app/views/template/top.php"    ;
        include "app/views/template/menu.php"   ;
        include "app/views/" . $url . ".php"; 
        include "app/views/template/bot.php"    ;
        include "app/views/template/footer.php" ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get much to go on here, but try and use the full path to your php files. eg. `include __DIR__ . "/app/views/template/header.php";`

Comment: First step is to make sure your PHP on your host is showing you ALL errors.  Then work from there ... if nothing is echoing out, there must be an error that's not being printed.  Usually hosts only show fatal errors and not warnings.

Comment: "Does not work" is not a valid php error message.

Comment: I hope you are properly sanitizing the `$url`-parameter beforehand, otherwise your script is vulnerable to local file inclusions (which in turn could be used to run code or disclose sensitive information).

Comment: @tereško: The OP did say "the html i include in my view.php(MVC) is not been added to the page" after "Does not work"

Comment: also ... dear, @user2057856. I would like to inform you, that MVC does not stand for "my very code".

Comment: @tereško yes i know that MVC stands for model view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MVC` is just an architecture paradigm and does not have any additional requirements (usually) that will cause it to break when migrating from server to server. What has happened here in most probability is that paths have got messed up when you moved it to the server.

Try these:

1. Set error_reporting to E_ALL and see if you get any errors/warning
2. Change include to required so that the page will die if the includes cannot be found
3. instead of include, try echo so that you can see the paths of the files being added
4. It is always desirable to use paths using `document root` or `basepath()` to avoid issues when moving servers

Comment: i have no errors nor warnings i changed the include to require and i allready was using a base tag. still i wont get my html been input.

Comment: check www.broersma-state.nl and you see no html is included

Comment: and it is completely functional in my localhost

Comment: did you set error reporting to all? try including full path just to see if that makes it work. If it does then check why relative path is not resolving correctly. If it does not then maybe one of the include has an error.

Comment: @user2057856 working in localhost does not really matter. There can be a number of things different in the server that can cause this irrespective of it works in local or not..

Comment: i`m not getting any errors nor warnings when i set the error to E_ALL